# Set "Description" in RestoreRequest for S3 object retrieval from GDA to Standard storage using AWS Java SDK v2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier, aws-java-sdk-2.x

Creating an *Object Restore request* from *AWS S3 Glacier Deep Archieve* to *AWS S3 standard storage* using AWS Java SDK V2 with the following code. **Which works successfully with these parameters specified for *restoreRequest object*!**

```
try {
        S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().build();
        System.out.println("S3 client created. . .");

        RestoreRequest restoreRequest = RestoreRequest.builder().description(
                .glacierJobParameters(GlacierJobParameters.builder().tier(Tier.STANDARD).build())
                .days(1)
                .build();

        RestoreObjectRequest objectRequest = RestoreObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket("myBucket")
                .key("data/myObject.zip")
                .restoreRequest(restoreRequest)
                .build(); 

        s3Client.restoreObject(objectRequest);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but by adding only one parameter **"description"** (as shown in code below) to the **restoreRequest**, the following exception is thrown on **s3Client.restoreObject(objectRequest)**.

```
try {
        S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().build();
        System.out.println("S3 client created. . .");

        RestoreRequest restoreRequest = RestoreRequest.builder().description(
                .glacierJobParameters(GlacierJobParameters.builder().tier(Tier.STANDARD).build())
                .days(1)
                .description("description about the object")
                .build();

        RestoreObjectRequest objectRequest = RestoreObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket("myBucket")
                .key("data/myObject.zip")
                .restoreRequest(restoreRequest)
                .build(); 

        s3Client.restoreObject(objectRequest);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 0Y7K1MVBGP5SP9FS, Extended Request ID: DZfX93DOWguFo0MVnTR3Awk9i5gG867rkZnTLU4bAueRQqjBhkq5eTjFWzltJRpxMYa5LmnWal0=)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:156)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:108)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:85)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:43)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:95)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$successTransformationResponseHandler$7(BaseClientHandler.java:245)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:50)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:36)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:81)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:167)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:82)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:175)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.restoreObject(DefaultS3Client.java:10422)
> at org.example.App.main(App.java:150)

Comment: WHat is the issue - you know the required values to make a successful call to restoreObject().

Comment: on adding the description to restoreRequest, the restoreObject() function call fails and exception is S3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: S3, Status Code: 400)
Since its a 400 (bad request) then it means issue is on client end (due to usage of description parameter). on removing description parameter, it works perfect.

Comment: @smac2020 please also check the same problem mentioned as 2nd issue, in following article.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/246